# Как создать подобный слайдер?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

Как создать подобный слайдер с помощью slicka, как менять дизайн срелочек?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
  $('.sl').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 300,
  fade: true,
  cssEase: 'linear'
});
```

```css
body{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: rgb(40, 40, 50);
}
header{
  height: 11vh;
  font-weight: 100;
}header :nth-child(1){
font-size: 30px;
margin-left: 5%;

}header :nth-child(2){
  margin-left: 60%;
  margin-top: -6%;
font-size: 33px;
}header :nth-child(2) img{
  padding-right: 1%;
}


header a{
font-size: 18px !important;
color: Peru;
padding-bottom: 3px;
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid Peru;
}header :nth-child(3){
  margin-left: 60%;
margin-top: -2%;

}


 span{
font-weight: bold ;
}
#section0{
    width: 100%;
   height: 120vh;
   position: relative;
   background: url('bezimeni-27_E1v9oDX.png') no-repeat center/cover;
color: white;
background-attachment: fixed;
}#section0 div{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-style: double; /* Стиль границы */
border-width: 4px;
  padding: 40px 40px 80px 40px;
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 27%;
position: relative;
top: 250px;
background: rgba(46, 46, 46, 0.8);
}#section0 div h1, #section0 div h3{
margin: 0px

}#section0 div h3{
  font-size: 38px ;
}#section0 div a{
  border: 2px solid white;
padding: 10px 16px;
font-size: 20px;
border-radius: 60px;
cursor: pointer;
color: white;
position: relative;
top: 30px;
}#section0 div a:hover{
  background: black;
}
#section1{
  margin-top: -4%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh;

  }#section1 .p{
    padding-top: 5%;

    font-size: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}#section1 .grid{
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(3,280px);
font-size: 20px ;
grid-gap: 20px 60px;
margin-left: 14%;
margin-top: 8%;
}#section1 .grid [alt='0']{
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 25px;
  z-index: 1;
}#section1 .grid [alt='1']{
padding-top: 30%;
margin-top: -31%;
border-top: 3px solid Peru;
left: 0px;
bottom: 25px;
z-index: 1;

}#section1 .grid [alt='2']{
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 25px;
  z-index: 1;
}
 [alt='0']{

z-index: 0;
position: relative;
left: 262px;
bottom: 500px;
 }[alt='1']{
   z-index: 0;
   position: relative;
   left: 478px;

   bottom: 500px;

 }[alt='2']{
   z-index: 0;
   position: relative;
   left: 686px;

   bottom: 500px;


 }

#section2{
background: silver;
height: 90vh;

}#section2 .p{
  text-align: center;
padding-top: 7%;
font-size: 40px;
position: relative;

}
#section2 .p:before{
    position:absolute;
    top: 119%;
    left: 47%;
    width:5%;
    border-bottom:3px solid Peru;
    content:"";
}
.main{
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="1.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
<header>
  <p><span class="span">DESIGN</span>STUDIO</p>
  <p><img src="0.png" alt="">8 800 000-00-00</p>
  <p><a href="#">Заказать звонок</a></p>
</header>
<section id="section0">
<div class="">
<h1>РАЗРАБОТКА</h1>
<h1>ФИРМЕННОГО СТИЛЯ:</h1>
<h3>от идеи до реализации</h3>
<a href="#">↓</a>
</div>
</section>
<section id="section1">
  <p class="p">РАБОТАТЬ С НАМИ <span>ЛЕГКО И ПРИЯТНО</span></p>

  <div class="grid">
<div class="div0">
<img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/245037/bezimeni-3_qwMWvjt.png#size_60x60" alt='0'>
<p><span>СОБЛЮДАЕМ СРОКИ</span></p>
<p>Разрабатываем лучшие
креативные идеи
и тщательно следим
за соблюдением сроков</p>
</div>
<div class="div1">
<img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/245037/bezimeni-2_O1bIEFo.png#size_56x60" alt='1'>
<p><span>ТАЛАНТЛИВЫЕ ДИЗАЙНЕРЫ</span></p>
<p>Высококвалифицированные
профессионалы, которые
мыслят ярко и нестандартно</p>
</div>
<div class="div2">
<img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/245037/bezimeni-1_OmiiQCk.png#size_60x52" alt='2'>
<p><span>ДОСТУПНАЯ ЦЕНА</span></p>
<p>Гибкая система расценок
позволяет сотрудничать как с крупными компаниями,
так и с частными лицами</p>
</div>
  </div>
</section>
<img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/245037/bezimeni-7_UJJtw4y.png#size_126x126" alt="0" class="">
<img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/245037/bezimeni-5_ltDSD24.png#size_126x126" alt="1" class="">
<img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/245037/bezimeni-6_X9sbs1e.png#size_126x126" alt="2" class="">

<section id="section2">
<p class="p">НАШЕ <span>ПОРТФОЛИО</span></p>
<div class="main">
  <div class="sl">
  <div class="slide__slide">
    <img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/245037/bezimeni-14_29JPQGq.png#size_355x355" alt="Картинка слайда 1" class="imgSlide__img">
  
  </div>
  <div class="slide__slide">
    <img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/245037/bezimeni-15_gu3xAbi.png#size_355x355" alt="Картинка слайда 2" class="imgSlide__img">
    
  </div>
  <div class="slide__slide">
    <img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/245037/bezimeni-12_2vWLtcK.png#size_355x355" alt="Картинка слайда 3" class="imgSlide__img">
  
  </div>
  <div class="slide__slide">
    <img src="https://media.lpgenerator.ru/images/245037/bezimeni-13_qOo3I8l.png#size_355x355" alt="Картинка слайда 4" class="imgSlide__img">
  
  </div>
</div></div>
</section>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
 <script src="slick.js">

 </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Объясните конкретно на моём примере плиз

Comment: я же ответил в комментарии тебе , что там не ясно ?

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите на мой пример, таким образом вы можете оформить кнопки Prev\Next как вам угодно. Так же рекомендую все таки более детально ознакомиться с документацией slick

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  arrows: false
})

$('.left').click(function() {
  $('.slider').slick("slickPrev");
})

$('.right').click(function() {
  $('.slider').slick("slickNext");
})
```

```css
.slider {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>

<p class="left">left</p>
<p class="right">right</p>
```

Comment: до чувака не доходит я ему в прошлом его вопросе дополнил комментарем вот это : https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/pozyPoW

Comment: @MaximLensky да увидел коммент выше и пробежался по истории ^_^ Думаю всё очень плохо... :-(